# Does registration location differ for Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

I'm checking the [ASP.NET Core MVC integration documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html) of Simple Injector and I see that registrations are done in `Configure` method of the `Startup`. Does it matter if they are done in `ConfigureServices` method instead? Will `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` method still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter if they are done in ConfigureServices method instead?

No, it doesn't. Both in `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` there is a reference to the container, so you can use both locations to make registrations.

The reason the documentation shows that registrations are made during `Configure` is because at that point in time the built-in configuration system has been built and some services are only available at  `ConfigureServices`.

Good example of this is the `IApplicationBuilder` service, which is your entry-point to the ASP.NET Core configuration system. You'll need the `IApplicationBuilder` to register your MVC controllers and View Components in Simple Injector.

> Will `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` method still work?

<strike>No, it won't. `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` is an extension method on `IApplicationBuilder`, which is only available during `ConfigureServices`.</strike>

The `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` extension method on `IApplicationBuilder` has been deprecated with the release of v4. Instead, a new `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` overload on `IServiceCollection` should be used instead, which means that `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping` should now actually be called inside `ConfigureServices` instead of `Configure`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);

    // more code here
}
```